Recursive Pascal Triangle Entry Calculator
I was trying to do a Pascal's triangle entry calculator in COBOL. I wanted to try to use a recursive function. I am a beginner so I looked online for how one may implement this kind of function in COBOL and it seems that it is unadvisable to do so. Anyway, just wanting to try, I wrote the code for the program, but it is not working properly. I tried a bit to understand why it doesn't work but I have no clue. Here is the code.
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. PASCAL RECURSIVE.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 ADDENDO1 USAGE IS BINARY-LONG.
       01 ADDENDO2 USAGE IS BINARY-LONG.
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 X USAGE IS BINARY-LONG.
       01 Y USAGE IS BINARY-LONG.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY VALUE X Y.
           IF X<0 OR Y<0 OR Y>X THEN
                 MOVE 0 TO RETURN-CODE
                 GOBACK
           END-IF.
           IF Y=X OR Y=0 THEN
               MOVE 1 TO RETURN-CODE
               GOBACK
           END-IF.
           COMPUTE X = X - 1.
           CALL "PASCAL" USING BY VALUE X Y
           RETURNING ADDENDO1.
           COMPUTE Y = Y - 1.
           CALL "PASCAL" USING BY VALUE X Y
           RETURNING ADDENDO2.
           COMPUTE RETURN-CODE = ADDENDO1 + ADDENDO2.
           GOBACK.
       END PROGRAM PASCAL.
       
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. pascaltrianglepost.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 N PIC S99.
       01 K PIC S99.
       01 CASELLA PIC 9(8).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-PROGRAM.
           ACCEPT N.
           ACCEPT K.
           CALL "PASCAL" USING BY VALUE N K RETURNING CASELLA.
           DISPLAY  CASELLA.
           STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM pascaltrianglepost.

To clarify, N is the above number in the binomial coefficient of the entry and K is the bottom one.
The same holds for X and Y in the program. The top of the triangle is the "coordinate" (0,0). The first row is made of (1,0) and (1,1), etc...
For example, if I use N=4 and K=2 as inputs, I expect to get 6 as a result. But the program returns 5. I also checked with displays and the program calculates the two entries above 6 correctly as threes. But somehow then the program adds 3 and 2 and gets 5. I wanted to know if my program is not correct inherently or if the problem has something to do with the way COBOL treats recurrences.

In the PASCAL program, change WORKING-STORAGE SECTION to LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
1 *2*  1
1 *3* -3- 1
1  4   6  4 1

With WORKING-STORAGE there is only one copy of ADDENDO1 and ADDENDO2. ADDEND01 was being changed with each recurrence. (The 3 shown in hyphens was overwritten.) The 2 was left over from adding 2 and 1 to get the final 3 (ADDEND02) before terminating. (Shown in asterisks.)
Changing to LOCAL-STORAGE, there is one copy of ADDENDO1 and ADDENDO2 for each recurrence. Thus the value of ADDENDO1 (the 3 shown in hyphens) is preserved as the other calculations occur.
I had to make some minor modifications to test on my older compiler. but that was the only significant change.

Yeah that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

@FrancescoRasoStoia Would you mind marking this answer as "worked for you" ()(accepted answer)?

COBOL doesn't do great with the concept of recursion in the sense of a program having a paragraph call itself. You get invalid results because when the paragraph ends, it ends. So the first exit condition you hit will end the entire paragraph and you won't execute follow-up instructions. IBM has indicated that this sort of thing of being recursive on a subroutine "can" work, but more in the sense of a subroutine CALLing a calling program.

For example, program X calls program Y, program Y calls program Z, and
program Z then calls program X.
source: https://www.ibm.com/docs/fi/cobol-zos/6.2?topic=subprograms-making-recursive-calls

This is a little different where your calling program is calling itself. Based on what I'm seeing, this will depend on the type of COBOL you are using. I'm assuming this is gnuCOBOL, so not sure aobut them, but IBM has indiacted ILE COBOL does support this, with some restrictions about what the program can do when used in this situation (source: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=paragraph-recursive-clause). I would suggest looking further into the type of COBOL you are working with to determine what your limitations are.
Personally, I would not bother with the recursion if you just want the triangle coded in COBOL and nest some loops (PERFORM UNTIL) and see if that is easier if your version indeed does not support recursion.

I started trying with recursion because I did not want to use an array. Because then I have to decide the maximum rows of the triangle that the program can write in the code and I foumd that inelegant. But if there is a way to not decide that in advance and not use recursion I am interested in knowing it. My mind could not find one.
